# IE8 returns with res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm, maybe related to jcarousel?

Tags: drupal, internet-explorer-8, jcarousel

I've been trying to solve this IE8 bug but keep running into dead ends.

We have a drupal 7 site. Our site works fine in all browsers except IE8.  It has to be IE8 on Windows XP...not the similators/emulators.  It seems to work fine in IE7, 9, and 10.  In IE8 it tries to reach our site and then it returns with res://ieframe.dll/acr_error.htm#[http://url.of.site] and fails to load the home page.

Other notes: other pages seem to load just fine if you know the full url.

The home page uses nice menus, flexslider, and jcarousel (v.0.2.8).  I noticed that when I decreased the carousel items so that there are no pagers, it seems to bring it back, at least in our development version. But we need to have more than one page of items, which is the whole point of using jcarousel.

I think I narrowed it down to jcarousel because the site works when I disabled the jcarousel. When I disabled everything else except the jcarousel, it crashes again.

There aren't any bg images to the body. We're running on jquery 1.8.2. I tried uncompressing and compressing all CSS and JS files. I tried changing the meta tag to force IE to emulate other versions. I tried changing the doctype.

Nothing works. And I'm not familiar with debugging in IE (beyond using the F12 developer tools) especially if the page fails to load.

Another odd thing is that I tried to use a different module to accomplish the same effect and it also crashes in IE8.

I'd appreciate any help.  Here's our url: http://www.frick.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue.  I updated the page.tpl.php, template.php.  I hadn't updated them in forever, and that seemed to have done the trick.